# read bash array from property file into a script

Tags: python

1. I've a property file abc.prop that contains the following.

   ```
   x=(A B)
   y=(C D)
   ```
2. I've a python script abc.py which is able to load the property file abc.prop.
   But I'm not able to iterate and convert both the arrays from abc.prop as follows,

   ```
   x_array=['A','B']
   y_array=['C','D']
   ```

   3. I tried the following, but I want to know if there's a better way of doing it, instead of using replace() and stripping off braces.

   `importConfigFile = "abc.prop"
   propInputStream = FileInputStream(importConfigFile)
   configProps = Properties()
   configProps.load(propInputStream)
   x_str=configProps.get("x")
   x_str=x_str.replace("(","")
   x_str=x_str.replace(")","")
   x_array=x_str.split(' ')`

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: updated the post, plz take a look.

Comment: what about regex?

Comment: ya regex works...but are there any out of the box solutions to this problem?...I mean is there any support in Python for arrays in bash format?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any special bash to python data structure converters. And I doubt there are any. The only thing I may suggest is a little bit cleaner and dynamic way of doing this.

```
data = {}
with open('abc.prop', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split('=')
        key = parts[0].strip()
        value = parts[1].strip('()\n')
        values = value.split()
        data[key] = [x.strip() for x in values]
print(data)
```